# Afraid to tell the truth about someone

Tags: single-word-requests

Simple one word to describe a feeling of uncertainty or anxiety about telling someone something very important but possibly damaging to either oneself or the person in question.

Comment: [Trepidation](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/trepidation) may not be specific enough, but it's the closest I know of.

Comment: Sounds *suicidal*. When I can't formulate the exact words to express something controversial, I conclude it's better left unsaid. Similarly, people occasionally preface a provocation by asking if it's okay to proceed, as in "I hope you won't find this racist, but..." I end that by suggesting that if they have to ask, and it may end up unwelcome, "please don't proceed."

Comment: also this could be ***shame***

Comment: Please include a sample sentence of how you would use this word.  Put an X or _____ where the word you're looking for would go.

Comment: I think I got some great feedback and will use trepidation.  I also like reticent and will use this word in a future description of emotional conflict.  The answers were great and I will try to better define my problem in future questions.

Comment: That's too much to pack into just one word. // *Reticent*, to me, doesn't necessarily convey emotional conflict.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider  '**reticent**'

It applies more directly to communication than some of the other words of concern, although the idea of "concern" is more a matter of "reservation" .

> [***reticent*** at Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/reticent)
>
> 1. taciturn, quiet, uncommunicative.
>
> 1.
>   not open or communicative; not saying all that one knows; taciturn; reserved
>
> *The New York Times, usually so reticent on sex-scandal stories, has named her and run the picture.*
>
> *Leno asked why he has been so reticent to publicize his opinions about President Obama and his policies.*

While one definition can me "quiet" of nature the context of most sentences you would use it in for your stated purpose would strongly suggest a ~reluctance~ to say something for some reason beyond a being a quiet type.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use "apprehension", although one could argue that it's not strong enough.

Comment: Jim, please see my comment below Xanne's answer.